# which images dockerd starts automatically?

Tags: configuration, docker, containers

Once I have restarted the docker service on Ubuntu box with `service docker restart` it started some of the containers I didn't expect it to start.

Why is that?  Which config file/storage/whatever holdw information about which images should be started?

I have a lot of images (~50) when listing them with `docker images`.  But only 8 of them start when I start the `dockerd`.  Why?  How do I chage this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

For individual containers, there is a restart policy you can apply. That's set with `docker run --restart=...` when starting the container, or a `restart: ...` line in the compose yml file. You can change the restart policy in an existing container with:

```
$ docker update --restart=... ${container_name_or_id}
```

To list all containers and their restart policies, you can run this from bash:

```
$ docker container ls -q | \
  xargs docker container inspect --format \
          '{{ .Name }}: {{.HostConfig.RestartPolicy.Name}}'
```

The [restart policies](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#restart-policies-restart) you can use are:

> **no**    Do not automatically restart the container when it exits. This is
>   the default.
>
> **on-failure[:max-retries]**  Restart only if the container
>   exits with a non-zero exit status. Optionally, limit the number of
>   restart retries the Docker daemon attempts.
>
> **always**    Always restart the
>   container regardless of the exit status. When you specify always, the
>   Docker daemon will try to restart the container indefinitely. The
>   container will also always start on daemon startup, regardless of the
>   current state of the container.
>
> **unless-stopped**    Always restart the
>   container regardless of the exit status, but do not start it on daemon
>   startup if the container has been put to a stopped state before.

A restart policy of `always` would result in an unexpected container restart after the docker daemon restarts like you are seeing, even if you had intentionally stopped the container. For this reason, I typically create standalone containers with a `unless-stopped` restart policy.

---

If you are using docker swarm mode, then services will automatically start up a new container any time the target state doesn't match the current state. For a single node swarm cluster often seen with laptops, this means the container will restart when you restart docker, but also if you just stop or delete the running container.

The permanently stop and remove a service:

```
$ docker service ls # to show the running services
$ docker service rm ${service_id_or_name}
```

If a service is configured with replicated mode, and you simply want to stop it temporarily without deleting the service, you can update the target replicas to 0:

```
$ docker service update --replicas=0 ${service_id_or_name}
```

And services may be deployed as part of a stack. To remove the entire stack:

```
$ docker stack ls # to show the defined stacks
$ docker stack rm ${stack_id_or_name}
```

Comment: When I enter `docker service ls`, I get `Error response from daemon: This node is not a swarm manager...`. I use `docker ps` instead

Comment: @rubo77 You may have missed the start of that section that begins with "If you are using docker swarm mode..."

Answer (score 2):

It means some of your containers have RestartPolicy set to always. This means the container has to be always up. Please inspect these containers in question, specifically checking the value of RestartPolicy.

```
$ docker inspect container-name
```

This usually happens when a container was created with a flag `--restart` always

To disable container from auto starting, use the command:

```
$ docker update --restart=no container-name
```

Another way around this is to set RestartPolicy to unless-stopped when starting the container. You can read full documentation of [docker update](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/update/)

Comment: I recommend "restart=unless-stopped" instead of just "no"

Answer (score 1):

Look into docker restart policy such as `--restart always`. I am guessing some of your containers are using that. Check your service startup script for docker. You can use `docker ps -a --no-trunc` to see the full list.

Answer (score 1):

Images don't start automatically, containers do.

On `service docker restart` containers that where **stopped** or **started** with `--restart always` flag will be started again automatically on restart. Check these via `docker ps -a`.

If you don't want a container to start (even one with `--restart always` flag), you simply need to remove it, `docker rm container` or `docker-compose down`.